# How to enforce the type of a global variable?

Tags: variables, powershell, types

In PowerShell, you can enforce the type of a local variable by prefixing the declaration with a type name:

```
[string]$MyString = 'hello'
```

Or you can create a global variable using the new-variable command

```
New-Variable -Name MyGlobalOption -Scope Global -Value [MyEnum]'Option1'
```

Built in global variables can enforce their types:

```
# This fails due to invalid cast to [ActionPreference]
$ErrorActionPreference = Get-Date
```

But self-defined global variables do not:

```
# Works just fine. And now $MyGlobalOption is invalid:
$MyGlobalOption = Get-Date
```

How can you enforce the type of a global variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try declaring it like this:

```
[MyEnum]$global:MyGlobalOption = 'Option1'
```

If I do this:

```
>  Set-StrictMode -Off
> [int]$global:MyGlobalOption = 1
> $MyGlobalOption = get-date
Impossibile convertire il valore "20/09/2013 18:00:18" nel tipo "System.Int32". Errore: "Cast da 'DateTime' a 'Int32'
non valido."
In riga:1 car:1
+ $MyGlobalOption = get-date
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

I got an error. I can't replicate your issue.

Comment: This is no different that using `New-Variable`, and it does not enforce the type. `$global:foo = [int]0; $global:foo = @{}; $global:foo.GetType()` returns `[HashTable]`

Comment: I can't test it now, but usually IIRC I declare variable in this way and the type is enforced. When I'll be on a computer I'll come back... maybe can dependes of strict mode I use...

Comment: @JoshuaHonig I'm sorry but I can't replicate you issue.

Comment: Interesting! Note however the first example you placed the type in from of the value, while in the second you placed it in from of the variable name: `[int]$global:foo = 0` vs `$global:foo = [int]0`

Comment: @JoshuaHonig OMG! I have not noticed until you did  tell me :P

Answer (score 0):

The type of the variable is determined by the type in square-brackets placed before the variables name when it is being assigned.

```
# This variable is constrained to [DayOfWeek]
[System.DayOfWeek]$day_1 = [System.DayOfWeek]::Monday

# This variable can be assigned anything, but _happens_ to be a [DayOfWeek]
$day_2 = [System.DayOfWeek]::Tuesday

$day_1 = 'humpday' # => MetadataError: Cannot convert value "humpday" to type "System.DayOfWeek". 
$day_2 = 'humpday' # => Works just fine
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to apply a type constraint like this when using any of the `{x}-Variable` commands, unfortunately.

If you need extra options afforded by `New-Variable`, like `ReadOnly`, you can use `Set-Variable` on an existing variable to update only those options:

```
PS > Get-Variable day_1 | Format-List

Name        : day_1
Description : 
Value       : Monday
Visibility  : Public
Module      : 
ModuleName  : 
Options     : None
Attributes  : {System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute}


PS > Set-Variable day_1 -Description "This is now read-only AND 
restricted to [DayOfWeek]." -Option ReadOnly
PS > Get-Variable day_1 | Format-List

Name        : day_1
Description : This is now read-only AND restricted to [DayOfWeek].
Value       : Monday
Visibility  : Public
Module      : 
ModuleName  : 
Options     : ReadOnly
Attributes  : {System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute}
```